# How to put telegram mtproto secret code in a file?

Tags: linux, shell-script, c

How to put telegram mtproto's secret codes in a file and then read it?
first I made

```
nano /etc/systemd/system/MTProxy.service
```

and then past this code

```
[Unit]
Description=MTProxy
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/opt/MTProxy/
ExecStart=/opt/MTProxy/objs/bin/mtproto-proxy -u nobody -p 8888 -H  443 -P a228$ -S a704c6af27e86da1eccf7e66c46c7324 -S cd305c6ce6d02ce57eee8fec3eab09b5 -S e0b157fdf6809e136dfef71bf5692d7f --aes-pwd proxy-secret  proxy-multi.conf -M 1
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

because I have 31 Secret code and it's hard to put them in a line like

```
-S <secret> -S <secret> -S <secret> -S <secret> -S <secret> -S <secret> -S <secret> -S <secret> -S <secret>
```

I need to put Secret codes in a file and then simply insert them in

```
ExecStart=/opt/MTProxy/objs/bin/mtproto-proxy -u nobody -p 8888 -H  443 -P a228$ -S HEREEEEEEEEEEEEEE --aes-pwd proxy-secret  proxy-multi.conf -M 1
Restart=on-failure
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a huge difference in the amount of work between writing the passwords in the unit file with -S ahead of each one versus writing them in a password file. Would the password file be maintained independently?

Comment: Write a simple shell script that reads your "secret code" file line by line, and generates `-S` arguments for each line, and then calls `mtproto-proxy` with these arguments. Call your script instead of `mtproto-proxy` from the systemd unit.